# surfaceChanged callback not firing when dialog is resized

Tags: android, android-view, android-alertdialog

I have a simple camera app, and i'm using a surfaceview inside an alertdialog to show the viewfinder. I noticed that if I manually resize the viewfinder by changing the size of the alertdialog, the surfaceChanged() callback does not fire on orientation change. If i comment the setlayout line it fires just fine. Am I missing a flag or configuration setting?

Thanks for any input.

code:

```
mBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
mBuilder.setTitle("test dialog");
mAlertDialog = mBuilder.create();

mFrameLayout = new FrameLayout(mContext);
mSurfaceView = new SurfaceView(mContext);
mFrameLayout.addView(mSurfaceView, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

mAlertDialog.setView(mFrameLayout, 0, 0, 0, 0);

mSurfaceView.getHolder().addCallback(mSHcallCallback);

mAlertDialog.show();

mAlertDialog.getWindow().setLayout(200, 600);
```

this is defined outside the activity class

```
SurfaceHolder.Callback mSHcallCallback = new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
            int height) {

        Log.d(TAG, "surface changed h:"+height+",  w:"+width);

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You will find your answer in below link
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceHolder.html